# Error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Missing api_key/current_key object

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

After updating my google play services i am getting this error. I am not sure why  this is happening. I am trying to implement Firebase for the first time.
Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my app level gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.deepak.firebasechatapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

So, can anyone please tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-syncing your api key with firebase
Go to Tool->Firebase and in the assistant that opens choose your service and hit "Connect to Firebase"

Solved it for me